# django-storage: How to store media files using sftp to a folder in aws instance

Tags: django, sftp

I have a requirements, I want my media files to be stored at an ubuntu aws instance

I have the `IP address` and the `.pem` file to access the instance via ssh

I have installed `django-storages` package

I am not sure how to setutp this package to store files on an aws instance.

I have to add the following settings into `settings.py` file for `django-storages`

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.sftpstorage.SFTPStorage'

SFTP_STORAGE_HOST = 'AWS elastic ip'
SFTP_STORAGE_ROOT = 'folder on AWS'
SFTP_STORAGE_PARAMS = {
    .... HOW TO PASS KEY HERE
}
SFTP_STORAGE_INTERACTIVE = False
```

and use in models as

```
from storages.backends.sftpstorage import SFTPStorage
SFS = SFTPStorage()

class Configurations(BaseModel):
name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
file = models.FileField(upload_to='configurations', storage=SFS)
descriptions = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

So how to do this

Also I how to check for know hosts

Comment: it's a dictionart, just send key value pairs: `SFTP_STORAGE_PARAMS = {
    'username': 'root',
    'password': 'password',
    'allow_agent': False,
    'look_for_keys': False,
}`

Comment: what about the `pem` file. I cant use username and password

Comment: Why you didn't mention it on Q?

Comment: in the second line

Comment: Omg. Sorry. Did you try with _key_filename (str) – the filename, or list of filenames, of optional private key(s) and/or certs to try for authentication_? `={'key_filename': 'path to file and file'}` (it's don't needed to put IP for twice, just in `SFTP_STORAGE_HOST`)

Comment: please can you show an example as answer.